# OCR: Saving Words in a CSV-file

Tags: python, pandas, ocr

this is a part of my OCR code. This part looks for a special word in a scanned PDF and prints this out. I have like 10 Queries like this and all print me the word I am looking for. Now I want to get the found words saved in a CSV, but I don't know how to do that. Can Someone help me, please?

```
QueryNumberZW = (ErgebnisPandas.query('Word=="ZW" & Wordindex<40 & Page==1').index.tolist())
print(QueryNumberZW)

if QueryNumberZW: 
    ResultNumberZW = (ErgebnisPandas['Wort'].iloc[QueryNumberZW[0]:QueryNumberZW[0]+3])
    ResultNumberZW = ' '.join(ResultNumberZW)
 
    print(ResultNumberZW)

´´´
```

Comment: first `append()` words to `list`. Next you can use standard module [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to write this list.

Comment: Could you give me an example?

Comment: don't you know how to use `list` and `append()`? And examples for `csv` you have in link.

Comment: it seems you use `pandas` - so you may convert `list` to `DataFrame` and use `df.to_csv(filename)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is basic knowledge.

Create empty list at start, append() words to list, and later write all list using `csv` or `pandas`

I have no idea which variables you want to save

```
# - at start -
all_words = [] 

# ... your code ...
all_words.append( word )

# - at the end -
df = pd.DataFrame({"words": all_words})
df.to_csv("words.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mate, Sorry I have started coding just a few weeks ago...